# How do I get the results of a group_and_count using the Sequel gem?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I have a Sequel-based class that I need to do some summaries on.

I'm doing a `group_and_count`, and I can see that it's generating the right query. However, when I try to access the results, Sequel is trying to coerce the rows into the class I'm accessing through:

```
[33] pry(main)> grouped = Pancakes::Stack.active.group_and_count('health_state')
=> #<Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset: "SELECT 'health_state', count(*) AS `count` FROM `pancakes_stacks` WHERE (`deleted_at` IS NULL) GROUP BY 'health_state'">
[34] pry(main)> grouped.each_entry { |row| puts row }
I sequel: (0.001344s) SELECT 'health_state', count(*) AS `count` FROM `pancakes_stacks` WHERE (`deleted_at` IS NULL) GROUP BY 'health_state'
#<Pancakes::Stack:0x000000089251a0>
=> #<Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset: "SELECT 'health_state', count(*) AS `count` FROM `pancakes_stacks` WHERE (`deleted_at` IS NULL) GROUP BY 'health_state'">
[35] pry(main)> grouped.first
I sequel: (0.001502s) SELECT 'health_state', count(*) AS `count` FROM `pancakes_stacks` WHERE (`deleted_at` IS NULL) GROUP BY 'health_state' LIMIT 1
I sequel: (0.001243s) SELECT * FROM `pancakes_stacks` WHERE (`id` IS NULL) LIMIT 1
=> #<Pancakes::Stack:0x44b068c>
```

I can get what I need by working around the ORM stuff, but that appears to require me to re-implement the `active` method above, and figure out how to get the table name from the class name:

```
[38] pry(main)> groupie = grouped.db[:pancakes_stacks].where(deleted_at:nil).group_and_count(:health_state)
=> #<Sequel::Mysql2::Dataset: "SELECT `health_state`, count(*) AS `count` FROM `pancakes_stacks` WHERE (`deleted_at` IS NULL) GROUP BY `health_state`">
[39] pry(main)> groupie.each_entry { |row| puts row }
I sequel: (0.001598s) SELECT `health_state`, count(*) AS `count` FROM `pancakes_stacks` WHERE (`deleted_at` IS NULL) GROUP BY `health_state`
{:health_state=>nil, :count=>3}
{:health_state=>"healthy", :count=>10}
```

Isn't there an easier way? I've spent a lot of time on the [querying page](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/querying_rdoc.html#label-Grouping), but none of the examples show how to access the results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just want to add a `.naked` to your dataset, which will make the dataset return hashes instead of model objects.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the [square brackets](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/InstanceMethods.html#method-i-5B-5D) method to get the `:count` attribute for a row:

```rb
row[:count]
```